# How many numbers in Pascal's triangle satisfied that divides by 7?

Tags: algorithm

For integer n (1<=n<=10^8). Count to how many numbers in Pascal's triangle satisfied that divides by 7.
Suppose s(n) is the result with input is n.

For example, we have: `s(1)=s(2)=s(3)=s(4)=s(5)=s(6)=0`, `s(7)=6`. 
Because with n=7, we have: `1 7 21 35 35 21 7 1`. There are: `7,21,35,35,21,7` divide by 7.

Similarly, with n=8, we have: `1 8 28 56 70 56 28 8 1`. So `s(8)=6+7=13`.
So on... and I need to compute s(n) with n is very large number.

Ps: I know this problem relevant to Lucas's theorem but I don't know how to use it into this problem.

Comment: How do you get `7` for s(8)?  I see only 5.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question

Comment: http://kuanwh.com/pascal-divisibility/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work from the binomial coefficient expression:

```
n! / (k! * (n-k)! )
```

All you need to worry about here is how many factors of 7 are in the expression.  Count 7s in the numerator and each of the denominator terms.  That entry is divisible iff there are more such terms in the numerator.  Note that you can do this merely by checking the denominator values with integer divisions.

For instance, when n=7, you have 8 terms (k in [0,7]) in the expansion.  Except when k=7 or (n-k)=7, you have a 7 in `n!` that is not covered in the denominator.  Thus, the other 6 terms are divisible by 7.

When n=8, you have *two* terms (of nine) on each end that cover all the 7s.  Thus you have 5 terms divisible.  In each successive row, you will have one more entry in the row, and one more on *each* end that isn't divisible: you'll have 5, then 4, then 3, ... that are divisible by 7.  Row 13 will have no terms divisible by 7.

Then look at what happens on row 14: two 7s in the numerator, but only one in the denominator for each of the 15 entries *except* when k=7.  Extend this pattern.

The parameterization is left as an exercise for the student.  Note that you have a new case when you get as far as 49, because that introduces *two* 7s into the numerator.  You have an effect comparable to the one when you went from s=6 to s=7.

Is that enough guidance to get you moving?

Comment: I'm really thanks you for your comment, so my trouble is how to form dynamic programming for this problem!!

Comment: Even better, follow the analytic path I laid out, and obtain the result by direct computation.  You have clumps of seven consecutive integers, each of which has a trivial formula for its sum.  Those clumps can be parameterized, giving you a higher-level formula for the sums of sevens.  All you need to do is to compute the sums up to the breakpoint below your given value of `s`, and then do the partial sum for the rest.